# Flattening object to base level with ES6

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, flatten

How would you get this object:

```
const data = {
  importantData: {
    index: 0,
    about: 'test',
    ':sub': {
        index: 1
    }
  },
  telephone: {
    index: 2,
    nr: 1234567
  }
}
```

to this:

```
{
   importantData: {
    index: 0,
    about: 'test'
  },
  ':sub': {
    index: 1
  }
  telephone: {
    index: 2,
    nr: 1234567
  }
}
```

wtih ES6.

I had success with finding the '.sub' object and getting its properties. However, I could not find a way to delete it from 'importantData' object for what I created new object with assign and saved non-':sub' values.

Comment: Do you want to bring the `:sub` property up one level, or do you want to bring all nested properties up one level? Simplistically, this would just be `data[':sub'] = data.importantData[':sub']; delete data.importantData[':sub'];`.

Comment: Ah, the **delete** keyword, how could I forget? 

Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/fzghkfnq/1/

Comment: There is nothing in ES6 that would help here. Use whatever existing ES5 solution you have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unoptimized solution.

```
function flattenToOneLevel (data) {
  for (let key in data) {
    const selectorName = key;
    const styles = data[key];

    for (let _key in styles) {
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(styles[_key]) === '[object Object]') {
        data[_key] = styles[_key];
        delete data[key][_key];
      }
    }
  }

  return data;
}
```